# Halide function failing with an error `Input buffer b0 is accessed at 2, which is beyond the max (-1) in dimension 2`

Tags: halide

I'm converting COCO2017 dataset to RAW Bayer format using Approx-Vision [library](https://github.com/cucapra/approx-vision). It works just fine for most of the images, but fails for other images.

I am using [pipeline_V2.cpp](https://github.com/cucapra/approx-vision/blob/master/pipelines/common/pipeline_V2.cpp) which is run by this [python script](https://github.com/cucapra/approx-vision/blob/master/pipelines/common/run-pipe.py). For some images it fails with the following error:

```
root@167545c2c5e4:/approx-vision/pipelines/common# ./pipeline_V2.o /datasets/000000431848.png /datasets/ 
Error at ./pipeline_V2.cpp:153:
Input buffer b0 is accessed at 2, which is beyond the max (-1) in dimension 2
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Does any one know why that is happpeing or how to fix it?

Normally it is supposed to output a RAW BAYER image in `.png` format.

Answer (score 0):

The problem originates from image channels. The image must be 3 channeled of type `[HxWxC]` - where `C` is a number of channels.